# AngularJS and JS array access

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
var FirstName   = ["Mohammad","Alex","Mustafa","Youssef","Ed"];
var LastName    = ["Boryani","Jones","Safa","Khansa","Snow"];
var Name=[];
var IDInc       = FirstName.length;

for(i=0;i<IDInc;i++)
Name.push(FirstName[i]+" "+LastName[i]);

    let  app = angular.module('NameRecorder', []);
    
    app.controller('GenTable', ['$scope', '$window',

    function($scope, $window) 
    {
        $scope.names = $window.Name;
        console.log($window.IDInc);
    }
                               ]
                  );
```

Hello all, I have this AngularJS code that used to work in HTML.

After I moved it to a js file and used $window, it doesn't work anymore; console.log doesn't print anything not even the Name array.

I tried some javascript commands in he file to make sure the html main page accesses it and it does

Comment: Nevermind, there was an unused ng-controller that crashed the whole thing...

Comment: If the question is no longer relevant, please delete it.